# How can I execute a script when my laptop failed to suspend

Tags: suspend, power-management, error-handling

My laptop occasionally fails to suspend, resulting in it burning up it's battery (and sometimes getting roasty-toasty in my bag).  In `dmesg` I usually see this entry:

```
PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
```

In that event I'd like to be able to run a script which sounds the machine's buzzer, plays a sound, or otherwise helps alert me that the laptop didn't suspend.

I'm familiar with handling *successful* events via scripts in `/etc/pm/sleep.d`, but how would I detect a failure?

Comment: are you sure that on suspend failure, there isnt an immediate resume event you can detect?

Comment: as long as I can tell that the resume was due to a suspend failure then it'd be fine, but I don't want to sound a klaxon everytime I open my laptop

Comment: if you have a script `00myscript` it can note the time it was called for a suspend, and when called for a resume that is only a few seconds later, it could look at the end of the log for the error message and so know for sure.